# Стилизация элемента select

Tags: gwt, javascript, java, css

Как стилизировать элемент select (ListBox)? Необходимо убрать стандартную кнопку с треугольником.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [тут](http://mihalytch.org.ua/programming/js/styled-drop-down-list.html) сделано довольно неплохо.

Comment: Но тогда придётся писать весь ListBox самому.. т.е. новый контрол делать вместо стандартного.

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще вариант: запихнуть select в контейнер с overflow:hidden и сдвинуть вправо так, чтобы скрыть стрелочку.

Answer (score 1):

[Нормально](http://leaverou.me/2011/03/custom-select-drop-downs-with-css3/) это можно сделать только в Вебките и (с некоторыми плясками) в Файрфоксе. Но данный способ нужно ещё допиливать, чтобы оно хоть как-то работало в других браузерах.

Answer (score 0):

По этой ссылке очень простой и удобный плагин по стилизации селектов http://info.wsisiz.edu.pl/~suszynsk/jQuery/demos/jquery-selectbox/ ,все работает как часы в ие6-7 и нормальных браузерах. Единственно нужно в нижней части плагина убрать код, который навешивает размеры боксов на атрибут стайл. После этого все стили будут подтягиваться через цсс.